# IE Compatibility issue : a possible solution?

Tags: internet-explorer, cross-browser

I have been searching for the past three hours for a solution to my problem.
I just finished building a website for our company, and it works fine in Firefox 3.0, Safari 3.1, Chrome 1.0.154 and Opera 11.

In Internet explorer, it does not work at all (I have only tried IE7 and IE8. I am using JQuery 2 which also mean that I am limited to IE9+.

Anyways, I thought of a possible solution : what if I displayed the entire website in a flash window ? That way no matter which version of IE (that supports flash), people will be able to view the website normally, and my nightmares will be over.

Do you know of any technique/trick to achieve this ?

Thanks a lot !

Cheers.

EDIT 1 :

As requested, I provide below the home page code, + the css that goes with it. I'll let you test it out with any browser you want and see the result in IE ^^ :
http://www.fileconvoy.com/dfl.php?id=g15ca070e2414ccb3999353780aaa6ba73041229a0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Althought it would still be called a website, it sounds like you try to embed the actual website into something else. This basically means that you have a bigger problem to take care of.

Internet Explorer is a little different from other browsers sometimes but he still can be dealt with and that's the way it needs to be done. I would not recommend any workaround.

If you want to deal with IE, please provide some code that you think isn't working properly on IE but is fine with other browsers, people will be glad to help you investiguate. Otherwise, the easy way to get over your "nightmares" would be to instruct your user to get an up-to-date browser if its browser is too old.

Comment: I added a basic set of files that are the base of the website. you'll have the home page + css + javascript that goes with it. Just look at the difference, it's horrible ^^. I like your idea of asking my customers to update their browser. I just want to make sure that everything works fine in IE9+.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from being technically complex, this idea would have several drawbacks.

Firstly, what would the Flash window contain? If it was a rendering of the entire site to Flash, you would need to maintain it as you change the site, and probably reimplement dynamic content and functionality - a lot more effort than implementing a version for IE in the first place. The only other way it could work would be an entire web browser embedded inside the Flash plugin; that would be a complex and probably slow piece of software, and again would have its own quirks which you would need to code for.

Secondly, embedding an entire site in a plugin limits what the user can do with it: they have less control of the UI, poor support for history and bookmarking, and so on.